# Not logging ad exposure. No active activity. 'Google Admob RewardedVideo'

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, admob

I get an error when I want to switch to another activity. The problem started right now: 'Google Admob RewardedVideo' I was trying to add. There was no problem after adding the flag ad.

> 23198-23236/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Recording user
>   engagement, ms: 46984
>
> 23198-23236/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Activity paused, time: 84767609
>
> 23198-23236/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Not logging ad
>   unit exposure. No active activity
>
> 23198-23236/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Not logging ad exposure. No
>   active activity

Info:

> 21105-21105/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
>   showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
>
> 18621-18621/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
>
> 18621-18621/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run:
>   adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>
> 18621-18621/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>                                            adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.ext.ui
>
> 18276-18484/? I/FA-SVC: App measurement is starting up, version: 11302
>
> 18276-18674/? I/FA-SVC: This instance being marked
>   as an uploader
>
> 19034-19034/com.metabrain.emre I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11020
>
> 19034-19034/com.metabrain.emre I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb
>   shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>
> 19034-19034/com.metabrain.emre I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event
>   logging run:
>                                                             adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.metabrain.emre
>
> 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre I/FA: Tag Manager is not
>   found and thus will not be used

Verbose:

> 08-13 15:05:14.959 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre I/FA: Tag Manager is
>   not found and thus will not be used 08-13 15:05:14.992
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am,
>   ad_event_id(_aeid)=-949480578009143333}] 08-13 15:05:15.041
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Using measurement service 08-13
>   15:05:15.041 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Connection attempt
>   already in progress 08-13 15:05:15.043 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre
>   D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am,
>   ad_event_id(_aeid)=-949480578009143354}] 08-13 15:05:15.057
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Using measurement service 08-13
>   15:05:15.057 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Connection attempt
>   already in progress 08-13 15:05:15.085 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre
>   V/FA: Using measurement service 08-13 15:05:15.085
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Connection attempt already in
>   progress 08-13 15:05:15.087 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre D/FA:
>   Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Main_Activity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=-949480578009143353}] 08-13 15:05:15.101
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Using measurement service 08-13
>   15:05:15.101 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Connection attempt
>   already in progress 08-13 15:05:15.105 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre
>   V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 83370181 08-13 15:05:15.270
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000
>   ms. Event not sent. time: 184 08-13 15:05:15.270
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Using measurement service 08-13
>   15:05:15.270 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Connection attempt
>   already in progress 08-13 15:05:15.272 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre
>   V/FA: Activity paused, time: 83370365 08-13 15:05:15.306
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash,
>   timestamp=1502625915299, fatal=1}] 08-13 15:05:15.324
>   19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Using measurement service 08-13
>   15:05:15.324 19034-19069/com.metabrain.emre V/FA: Connection attempt
>   already in progress

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    ...
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.4"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(path: ':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Comment: Having same problem on Native ads. It just came up all of a sudden and kept printing these messages while swiping between pages in `ViewPager`.

Comment: I am not able to click on any single view from the main activity, this will work only after many click attempts.. Is this the reason? Are you facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced an issue like this with interstitial ads, and found that the user is trying to leave the activity while there is an interstitial add which is already loaded but not shown to the user yet. and I had solved the issue in the following manner:

1. Define a Boolean flag:

   ```
   private boolean addIsReady;
   ```
2. Set the flag status inside the adListener class when you load your ad:

   ```
   myAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                addIsReady = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                addIsReady = false;
            }
    }
   ```
3. set the flag to false just before showing your ad to the user inside a method like this:

   ```
   void showInterstitialAd(){
     if (mmAd == null) return;
        if (myAd.isLoaded()) {
            addIsReady = false;
            myAd.show();
        }
    }
   ```
4. check if the is already loaded before the user leaves the activity and if it's true show the already loaded ad to the user (this step solved the issue in my case)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       if (addIsReady){
           requiredLawIndex = -1;
           showInterstitialAd();
       }
       super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

I hope this answer could help you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the ad doesn't have much time to show. Before the ad is been shown, the calling activity is closed. So, better a better idea would be:

- Start the `B.activity` from `A.activity` with `A.activity#startActivityForResult()`
- Load ad inside `B.activity#orResume()`.
- Set result code when `B.activity` is finishing, i.e. in `B.activity#onBackPressed()` or `B.activity#onDestroy()`.
- Show ad in `A.activity#onActivityResult()`